# Delete all input element inside form jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element

How to delete all kind of input field inside a form when clicking a `href` element?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.delete-link').on('click', function() {
   //remove all input inside #form-delete
 });
</script>
```

```html
<form id="form-delete" action="/post>" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="test1" value="">
 <textarea name="test2" rows="8" cols="80">TEST</textarea>
 <input type="checkbox" name="test3" value="">
 <input type="number" name="test4" value="">
 <input type="password" name="test5" value="">
 <input type="email" name="test5" value="">
</form>

<a href="#" class="delete-link">
   <span>Remove All input</span>
</a>
```

Comment: `$("#form-delete").find("input").remove();`

Comment: `$("#form-delete").find(":input").remove(); `

Comment: @TylerRoper is it gonna delete the textarea too?

Comment: Nope. I took *"input field"* to mean `<input>` elements. If you want to delete `<textarea>` too, then you could do `$("#form-delete").find("input,textarea").remove();`

Comment: another option is `$("#form-delete").find("input,select,textarea").remove(); `

Comment: @TylerRoper https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments ?

Comment: @FatalMerlin [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions) - This question shows no attempt to solve the issue on their own. No research, nor code to debug. As such, I didn't submit an answer. *"Then why answer in the comments?"*: The question seemed innocuous enough that I wanted to help out, and being that OP seems new, I didn't feel it was an appropriate time to rattle the cage about rules (especially as the answer was a short one-liner).

Comment: @TylerRoper ahh, I see, that makes sense, I was just wondering :) Thanks for taking the time to explain it!

Comment: @FatalMerlin Not a problem :) In situations like these, I particularly like animuson's comment on the link I posted above: *"If you don't answer a question that's likely to be deleted, then you won't complain later when your reputation decreases because your answer got deleted with it.*"

Answer (score 2):

To delete all input tags values (clear the input text)

```
//when the Document Loads, add event to clears all input fields
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.delete-link').on('click', function() {
   $('input').val('');    
 });   
});
```

Try it
http://jsfiddle.net/9q6jywmg/

To actually remove the element itself

```
//Document Loads, add event to remove all input tagged elements
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.delete-link').on('click', function() {
   $('input').remove();
 });   
});
```

Try it
http://jsfiddle.net/hym5kde7/

Of course to remove `textarea` element, do the same by selecting `textarea` tagged elements also, like this

`$('textarea').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
document.getElementById('your_id').remove(); //also add ids to your input fields
```

Try it here!

http://jsfiddle.net/4WGRP/

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form-delete" action="/post>" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="test1" value="">
 <textarea name="test2" rows="8" cols="80">TEST</textarea>
 <input type="checkbox" name="test3" value="">
 <input type="number" name="test4" value="">
 <input type="password" name="test5" value="">
 <input type="email" name="test5" value="">
</form>

<a href="#" class="delete-link">
      <span>Remove All input</span>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.delete-link').on('click', function() {
 //remove elements
  // $('#form-delete').children('input').remove(); 
//remove values
   $('#form-delete').children('input').val('')
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.delete-link').on('click', function() {
   $('#form-delete [my-input]').remove();
 });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-delete" action="/post>" method="post">
 <input type="text" my-input='' name="test1" value="">
 <textarea my-input=''  name="test2" rows="8" cols="80">TEST</textarea>
 <input my-input=''  type="checkbox" name="test3" value="">
 <input my-input=''  type="number" name="test4" value="">
 <input my-input=''  type="password" name="test5" value="">
 <input my-input=''  type="email" name="test5" value="">
</form>

<button href="#" class="delete-link">
      <span>Remove All input</span>
</button>
```

Comment: text area is still there

Comment: @TinyDancer, its done  i have just provided custom attribute to every input, and on delete button i am finding all my custom inputs and removing them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `remove()` method:

```js
$(function(){
   $('.delete-link').on('click', function() {
   $("#form-delete").find("input").remove();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-delete" action="/post" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="test1" value="">
 <textarea name="test2" rows="8" cols="80">TEST</textarea>
 <input type="checkbox" name="test3" value="">
 <input type="number" name="test4" value="">
 <input type="password" name="test5" value="">
 <input type="email" name="test5" value="">
</form>

<a href="#" class="delete-link">
   <span>Remove All input</span>
</a>
```